# Why is the availability state of the azure function "Not applicable"

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an azure function that uses App service Plan. The status of availability of this Azure function is Not applicable. Do you know what could be the cause of this availability status? what should I do to change this status to "Available"? I have reset it many times but doesn't help?

[image]

Comment: On one of my function apps this is shown as "Loading..." then it disappears. Do your functions work - does it matter?

Comment: Hi Kaja, may I know if your problem was solved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Not applicable" caused by the selection of "Authorization level" when you create your function. When you add a new function in your function app, if you choose "**Function**" for the "Authorization level" box, it will show "Not applicable" on portal.(when you request this function, it needs a function key). If you choose "**Anonymous**" for the "Authorization level" box, it will show "Avaiable" on portal.(when you request this funciton, it will not require a function key)

Shown as below screenshot:

[image]